# How can I fix datatype mismatch when importing from csv to sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, csv, import, integer

I'm having a datatype mismatch error when I try to import data from a csv file that has integers only into a table in my database that has two columns of integer data types. I can't seem to pinpoint what is causing the issue. I even specified the separator to be comma in sqlite3

Below is a sample from my CSV

```
48,2015
125,2015
55,2015
```

Below is my table schema

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
Car_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Year INTEGER
);
```

Comment: The sample data loads fine.  Is the first row of the csv column headings? That would cause the error. Assuming importing with sqlite3, error tells you which row in csv failed.

Comment: Maybe it somehow interprets the comma as a decimal point?